# Window 8 Search Can't Find Files in Libraries

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-search

When I search for files under *Libraries* or any of its subdirectories, no results are returned. Here is a screenshot demonstrating the problem:
[image: Screenshot of search for * in Libraries]

Here is a screenshot showing the current search settings in *Folder Options*:
[image: Search tab in Folder Options showing my settings]

Here is a screenshot showing my indexing settings values:
[image: Screenshot of indexing options]

Here are some things I have already tried:

- There are files present.
- Windows Search service is running.
- The search query is OK.
- Searching in other places still works.
- Searching in the folders that are mapped to the library folders (such as C:\Users\username\Documents) still works.
- The built-in *Find and fix problems with Windows Search* tool did not find any problems.
- I've tried enabling *Always search file names and contents*.

**How can I get Windows Search to work correctly for *Libraries*?**

Comment: I don't get any results for * (star) on it's own.  What if you try *.pdf or *.txt or *.doc?

Comment: Apparently searching in all folders of a Library [*should* work](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Find-a-file-or-folder), but it's failing for me as well in Win7.

Comment: @GuyThomas, '*' works fine for me in other locations. I've tried other valid queries such as the ones you suggested, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer experience this problem in Windows 8.1 now that libraries have now been moved under *This PC*. Since it's a free upgrade for Windows 8 users, I think upgrading is an acceptable solution.

[image: Search results in Documents showing files]